# Why is the vibrational kinetic energy of a body ignored when calculating the total kinetic energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics, vibrations

In calculating the total kinetic energy of a macroscopic rigid body, we add the total translational kinetic energy and the total rotational kinetic energy of the constituent particles. Why is the total vibrational kinetic energy of the constituent particles left out?

Comment: I’ve removed a comment that should have been an answer, and replies to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A net force or torque on a rigid body will not affect its internal energy. As it remains constant before and after the application of the force/torque, it is not relevant to the equations of motion.

Comment: If friction acts on the body, the internal energy changes. Yet, even in the presence of friction, the vibrational kinetic energy is not included.

Comment: Good point. I guess the answer is that the increase in internal energy is << the changes in translational or rotational energies, but I hope someone else can comment.

Comment: Though it is possible that the increase in the internal energy is much less than the changes in translational and rotational kinetic energies, I don't think that is necessarily the case. Friction can cause significant changes in the internal energy of a body, the increase in temperature of a body when friction acts on it is sometimes quite large.

Comment: I think I've clarified my doubts on this issue. The vibrational kinetic energy does not change as long as the body is not acted upon by friction and other dissipative forces, it therefore appears on both sides of the energy conservation equation and is not included in calculations. When dissipative forces act on the body, it appears as if mechanical energy is not conserved and we say that some energy has converted to heat; though what's really going on is that the vibrational kinetic energy and internal potential energy of the constituent particles has increased.

Answer (score 0):

> we add the total translational kinetic energy and the total rotational kinetic energy of the constituent particles. Why is the total vibrational kinetic energy of the constituent particles left out?

We don’t actually leave out vibrational kinetic energy if the centre of mass of the system is vibrating.

---

This is a matter of scales at which you’re analysing the system. If you’re interested in the mechanics of the system, then you can get away with treating most solids as a rigid body where there is no relative motion between its constituents.

At this point I’d like to point out that for a multi-particle system, it’s convenient to decouple the motion as a centre of mass rigid body motion and “internal” motion about the centre of mass. The dynamics of the centre of mass is described by Newton’s laws. If the number of constituent particles is small, we can sort of get away with using Newton’s laws itself for the internal motion. But for the description of the internal motion of a large number of constituents, we need a different kind of dynamics. This is what we call thermodynamics, or more precisely, statistical mechanics.

Here comes a concept known as the [equipartition theorem](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/eqpar.html) which says that if we are at thermal equilibrium, then the energy of each kind of motion (translation, rotation, vibration) usually known as degrees of freedom, contribute equally. So you see, vibration is as relevant and equally represented as the other kinds of motion.

---

In a comment in another answer you have asked:

> If friction acts on the body, the internal energy changes. Yet, even in the presence of friction, the vibrational kinetic energy is not included.

We actually do have to consider all possible degrees of freedom. The energy is equally distributed to or taken from all of them. But as I said earlier, we rarely talk about internal energy when we are concerned with the macroscopic dynamics of a mechanical system.

Comment: So you mean that the vibrational kinetic energy is somehow included in the equation for the total kinetic energy even though it is not explicitly stated?

Comment: There is a distinction between macroscopic energy which is the energy of the centre of mass of the system, and the internal which is described by thermodynamics. In each case, **all** kinds of motion need to be considered while calculating the kinetic energy. Including vibrational.

Comment: Also, which equation is this that you’re taking about? What is the context?

Comment: The equation T=(1/2 Mv^2 ) + (1/2 Iw^2) where M is the total mass of the body  v is the velocity of its centre of mass, I is the moment of inertia of the body about its centre of mass and w is the angular velocity of rotation of the body about its centre of mass.

Comment: The first term represents the total translational kinetic energy of the constituent particles while the second term represents the total rotational kinetic energy of the constituent particles. The total vibrational kinetic energy is apparently not included.

Comment: Yes. The vibrational kinetic energy is included in the first term $Mv^2/2$ because the velocity $v$ is the overall velocity of the centre of mass. The thing that separates vibrational motion from regular translational motion is that vibration has an extra bit of energy. The potential energy of $kx^2/2$

Comment: In deriving the formula (a typical derivation can be found in chapter 10 of John R Taylor's Classical Mechanics) no reference was made to the vibrational kinetic energy of the constituent particles, the only energies considered are the translational and rotational  kinetic energies of the  constituent particles. How are we then justified in assuming that the vibrational kinetic energy has somehow been included?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113338/discussion-between-thorbah-and-superfast-jellyfish).

Answer (score 0):

Because the definition of rigid body requires that the distance between its points doesn't change. If we follow that model, only translations and rotations are possible.

If we modify the model from a rigid body to an elastic body, mechanical vibrations are included.

For a more complete description, heat transfer must be also included, resulting from external friction for example, and internal friction, as damping of mechanical vibrations, or even plastic deformations.

Comment: So if we treat the body as a rigid body, we have to assume vibrational motion of the constituent particles is absent even though we know that it is present. Won't that affect the accuracy of our result?

Comment: Yes, that is an approximation. But it can be enough depending on the situation.

Comment: But the constituent particles vibrate at quite high frequencies, which means that the total vibrational kinetic energy is significant. Why are we allowed to neglect such a term?